# Is there a tried and tested way of creating a .gitignore with all the known recommend ignores?

Tags: git, gitignore

Bit of a random question - but is there a known method for creating .gitignore files for recommended frameworks etc etc, for example:

Django:

```
*.pyc
db.sqlite3
```

node.js (and others):

```
/node_modules
```

php:

```
env.local.php
```

Just seems like I either a.) can't find this or b.) I'm not using git init or .gitignore creation correctly?

Comment: You can check https://github.com/github/gitignore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really like the gitignore templates from https://www.gitignore.io

[image]

Eg.

- Django: https://www.gitignore.io/api/django
- Node: https://www.gitignore.io/api/node

and you could also combine multiple frameworks, eg vim+visual studio: https://www.gitignore.io/api/vim%2Cvisualstudio

Last but not least, you could even integrate gitingore.io into the command line, so you could execute: `$ gi linux,java`. See the [docs](https://www.gitignore.io/docs) for that

Answer (score 2):

You can use A collection of .gitignore templates. http://github.com/github/gitignore